# What is the proper name of a "line account"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation

I've come across having to translate the Danish word "stregregnskab" to English. The direct translation would be "line account", but I seem to recall there being a proper name for this sort of account.

For the record, "stregregnskab" means an account such as the one shown below, usually used for counting consumption of beverages or points in games.

[image: A "line account"]

I feel that "line account" is a pretty poor translation, so I'm curious; what is the commonly accepted name for this sort of account?  (I am referring to the entire image here; not just the tally marks.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Your question has been closed as a duplicate of another. If you read that post and still don't feel that your question has been answered, then please feel free to edit this question to reflect what part of the answer in the duplicate you find confusing. If you have questions about why your post was closed, please leave a comment here or ask on [Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Thanks and welcome again!

Comment: Do you mean the lines which stand for numbers (tally marks), or the whole grid, including the names of the people, and what they drank?

Comment: @drm65: I mean the whole sheet. :)

Comment: @Seb: Then this is not a duplicate, and you can flag and let a moderator know.

Comment: @RegDwight: I don't really find it to be an exact duplicate, as it wasn't the marks I asked about, but it did lead me to an acceptable term; a tally sheet.

Comment: @Seb: I edited your question to make that clear.

Comment: @RegDwight: Is it still a dupe?  The term "tally sheet" really isn't evident in the answer to the proposed dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pointed towards the word "tally" by [RegDwight ♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/300/regdwight), which added further fuel to my Google searches.

I ended up finding the term [check sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_sheet), also called a tally sheet, which appears to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sebastian Paaske Tørholm: Cheers!

Comment: Check sheet is accurate but not what I'd consider a common term; I'd consider using **tally** or an alternative word like **scorecard** instead of it in conversation.

Answer (score 0):

In a bar where multiple drinks are being ordered throughout the night and we don't want to have to pay for each drink each time until the final bill is settled at the end of the night, we would simply ask the bartender to run a "tab", which is short for 'tabulate', meaning a running bill or account.